# RewriteRule acting strange adding query to some url and not to some others

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i'm designing a mvc application in php and I want to reformat and parse the url. My folders are as below:

- App
- Public

  - Assets
  - .htaccess

my htaccess file includes:

```
 Options -Multiviews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /mymvctest/public 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?url=$1 [END,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Index.php receives a "url" GET variable and prints it for the sake of this example.

if my input url is `/mymvctest/public/atestvalue` the final url will be the same,`/mymvctest/public/atestvalue`, and "atestvalue" will be printed in index too.

but when my input url includes a valid directory, the query is shown in the url. for example, if my url is `/mymvctest/public/Assets` the final url will be `/mymvctest/Public/Assets/?url=Assets`. The surprising part is that when i add a slash after "Assets", `/mymvctest/public/Assets/`, the final url will be be the same as my input url: `/mymvctest/public/Assets/`. I get the "url" variable in both cases though.

why is this happening!?

Comment: Please add your input url (full url) and expected outputs

Comment: @IndraKumarS   input url: "localhost/mymvctest/public/Assets"  -  expected url: "localhost/mymvctest/public/Assets"   -   result url: "localhost/mymvctest/public/Assets/?url=Assets"

Answer (score 1):

It is happening this way because `/mymvctest/public/Assets` is an actual directory. First `mod_rewrite` rule executes and makes it `/mymvctest/public/index.php?url=Assets` *internally*.

Apache has another module called `mod_dir` that (due to security reasons) catches all *original* URLs that point to a directory and have a missing trailing slash. It then redirects them to same path with a trailing slash with `R=301` thus making final URL as: `/mymvctest/public/Assets/?url=Assets`.

In other to prevent this behaviour, use

```
DirectorySlash off
```

However this might expose your directory content in browser. To prevent that use this directive as well:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 2nd and 3rd lines.

```
RewriteEngine On 
#if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Input Url :

> http://localhost/mymvctest/public/testvalue

> http://localhost/mymvctest/public/Assets/

Output Url :

> http://localhost/mymvctest/public/index.php?url=testvalue
>
> http://localhost/mymvctest/public/Assets/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've tried this too. And it works the same. And also the input url which results a different url is "Localhost/mymvctest/Public/Assets" with no slash in it.

Comment: Why do you want to omit "/" after assets ?

Comment: It's a possible input url. I want to know why apache behaves those two url differently.